# Plotly R - Include filter in the legend that doesn't affect graph

Tags: r, plotly

A feature of `plotly` that I really like is the ability to dive into the data by clicking on specific groupings in the legend. For example, if I set a column to color for a scatter plot, I can filter on the various color variables. However, I only know how to create this filter when assigning the column to color. Is there a way to assign a variable to the legend to filter without changing the design of the plot. For example is there a function like `legend_filter` in plotly I could use:

```
iris2 <- iris  
iris2$sample <- sample(c('A','B'), nrow(iris2), replace = T)

p <- plot_ly(data = iris2, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, color = ~Species,
#                   legend_filter = ~sample
                     )
p
```

such that 'A' and 'B' show up in the side bar to interactively click on, but aren't referenced on the graph?

Thanks

Comment: this might help: https://community.plot.ly/t/setting-initial-plot-to-be-a-subset-of-input-data-using-buttons-and-drop-downs/6624/2

Answer (score 2):

This method lets you toggle all of A and B on off as a group by clicking any one of the entries.

Legend is definitely cluttered side, and you have to add another set of markers for each level of your grouping variable. I don't think this is really the end result you're looking for, but I figured I might as well post anyway in case any pieces of it are useful.

```
plot_ly() %>% 
  add_markers(data = iris2[iris2$sample == "A",],
              x = ~Sepal.Length,
              y = ~Petal.Length,
              color = ~Species,
              legendgroup = "A",
              name = "A") %>% 
  add_markers(data = iris2[iris2$sample == "B",],
              x = ~Sepal.Length,
              y = ~Petal.Length,
              color = ~Species,
              legendgroup = "B",
              name = "B")
```

Yields
[image: plot]

Comment: Not what I'm looking for but you gave me an idea. What I could do is add markers for A/B like you have, but instead of adding a legend group I can add an All/A/B input dropdown that filters the data accordingly. Thanks!